# Is there a way of rewriting wss to https Apache 2

Tags: apache2, wss

Hi im currently trying to find a way to
switch out the protocol of a url.
Im having a server wich is running fine on its own but behind a apache reverse proxy its throwing the error connection to websocket failed.
The problem is that the Websocket is only locally available as wss:// through the ip of the server it gets switched to https://.
Is there any way to switch it back ok a apache reverse proxy?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to *switch* protocols. WSS and https are two different protocols - for a reason. If your app requires wss it requires wss.

What you want is to configure Apache to proxy https *and* wss for you. That can be done with `mod_rewrite`. Add something along the lines of the following to your vhost stanza:

```
ProxyRequests Off    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) wss://localhost:8123/$1  [P,L]
```

Comment: no i want to rewrite it because of unraid wich is using wss in the frontend but the protocol is https in the backend

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Unraid, so you should probably ask them to fix that bug.

Comment: There musst be another way

Comment: If frontend and backend of a product doesn't agree on what protool to use, it's a bug.

Comment: Could be but i’m not search for the cause im searching for a solution to fix the problem without changing the code of the server